# terraform: unable to link api gateway usage plan to stage, "api_stages.0.stage" is required

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am somehow unable to create an API gateway usage plan to its stage even though I followed what was given in the [docs](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/api_gateway_usage_plan).

This is the block of resource code.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "main" {
  name = var.project

  api_stages {
    api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
    stage  = aws_api_gateway_deployment.main.stage_name
  }

  quota_settings {
    limit  = 10000
    period = "WEEK"
  }

  throttle_settings {
    burst_limit = 5
    rate_limit  = 50
  }

  tags = var.tags
}
```

and the error msg when I `terraform apply`; which was strange when I already specified the stage arg & value.

```bash
Error: Missing required argument
│
│   with aws_api_gateway_usage_plan.main,
│   on main.tf line 112, in resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "main":
│  112: resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "main" {
│
│ The argument "api_stages.0.stage" is required, but no definition was found.
```

The entire script is as such.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api" "main" {
  # naming api gateway
  name        = "api-gateway-${var.project}-${var.env}"
  description = "API gateway for ${var.project}"
  tags        = var.tags
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_resource" "main" {
  # define API endpoint
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  parent_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.root_resource_id
  path_part   = "{proxy+}"
}


# method ------

resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "main" {
  # define the method(s), e.g. GET / POST / etc.
  resource_id   = aws_api_gateway_resource.main.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  authorization = "NONE"
  http_method   = "ANY"
}


# integration ------

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "main" {
  # link with a lambda function
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  resource_id = aws_api_gateway_resource.main.id
  http_method = aws_api_gateway_method.main.http_method

  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = var.lambda_arn
}


# deployment to stage ------

resource "aws_api_gateway_deployment" "main" {
  # deploy API to a stage
  rest_api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  depends_on = [
    aws_api_gateway_integration.main
  ]
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_stage" "main" {
  # define a stage
  deployment_id = aws_api_gateway_deployment.main.id
  rest_api_id   = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
  stage_name    = var.env
}

resource "aws_lambda_permission" "apigw_lambda" {
  statement_id  = "AllowExecutionFromAPIGateway-${var.project}-${var.env}"
  action        = "lambda:InvokeFunction"
  function_name = var.lambda_name
  principal     = "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
  source_arn = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.execution_arn}/*/*"
}


# API key ------

resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan" "main" {
  name = var.project

  api_stages {
    api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
    stage  = aws_api_gateway_deployment.main.stage_name
  }

  quota_settings {
    limit  = 10000
    period = "WEEK"
  }

  throttle_settings {
    burst_limit = 5
    rate_limit  = 50
  }

  tags = var.tags
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_api_key" "main" {
  name = "api-key-${var.project}"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_usage_plan_key" "main" {
  key_id        = aws_api_gateway_api_key.main.id
  key_type      = "API_KEY"
  usage_plan_id = aws_api_gateway_usage_plan.main.id
}
```

The versions used were

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 4.21.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = ">= 1.2.2"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the documentation I used was wrong/outdated. `aws_api_gateway_deployment.main.stage_name` does not have a stage name.

Before

```
  api_stages {
    api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
    stage  = aws_api_gateway_deployment.main.stage_name
  }
```

After

```
  api_stages {
    api_id = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.main.id
    stage  = aws_api_gateway_stage.main.stage_name
  }
```